# Unifying a real-valued function over two branches

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, numerical-methods

I have a function that I want to evaluate numerically. These three forms listed below are all identical algebraically for nonnegative real $u$ (aside from removable discontinuities at $u=0$ and $u=1$), but none avoids complex numbers for its entire domain.

$$\begin{aligned}
f_1(u) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1-u^2}}{u} \\
f_2(u) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\right) \\
f_3(u) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\ln\left(u+\sqrt{u^2-1}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

The first two have imaginary values of the square root for $u>1$ and the third has imaginary values of the square root for $u<1$. None are well-conditioned numerically in close proximity to $u=1$.

Any suggestions on a different form for numeric evaluation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the series expansion

$$\ln(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac2{2n+1}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{2n+1}$$

gives, according to the third representation,

\begin{align}f(x)&=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac2{2n+1}\left(\frac{x-1+\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x+1+\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)^{2n+1}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac2{2n+1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x+1}\right)^{2n+1}\tag{Rationalize}\\&=\frac1{x+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac2{2n+1}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{(x+1)^2}\right)^n\\&=\frac1{x+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac2{2n+1}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n\end{align}

which is convergent for all $x\ge0$ and is well-conditioned near $x=1$. It doesn't seem to be the case that there is a nice representation of $f$ over $\mathbb R_{\ge0}$, but for $x>1$ it is related to the inverse hyperbolic tangent function.

Comment: how is x related to u? (i'm just having trouble finding which algebraic manipulations produced that little tidbit)

Comment: yeah, sorry, I can't figure out how you reached your 2nd equation :/

Comment: @JasonS I substituted $u+\sqrt{u^2-1}$ into the logarithm and simply rationalized the quotient which comes from $(x-1)/(x+1)$.

Comment: ... ok well my brain works a bit more slowly... I guess I can see this working if you put $x=u+\sqrt{u^2-1}=u+\sqrt{(u+1)(u-1)}$ into $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ and then that becomes $\frac{\sqrt{u-1}}{\sqrt{u+1}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{u+1}+\sqrt{u-1}}{\sqrt{u-1}+\sqrt{u+1}}$ and the 2nd term there is 1

Comment: I edited in some steps, hopefully it should be clearer now.

Comment: 2nd to 3rd line is still fuzzy, but I can see how to get there myself. (also fyi 2nd line is missing exponent $2n+1$ instead of 2)

Comment: oh nm, about the $2n+1$ exponent; i missed the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: OK: so if you write for the numerator $N=x-1 + \sqrt{x^2-1} = \sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x-1} + \sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x+1}$ and for the denominator $D=x+1 + \sqrt{x^2-1} = \sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x+1}$ then....

Comment: ... $N/D = \frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x+1}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}}$ and the 2nd factor is 1, so $N/D = \frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x+1}} = \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}$.

Comment: Yes that works.